# analytical solution to equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve the following equation by $x$. (put sole $x$ on one side of the equation), but I am not sure if there is a analytical solution to this problem:

$$\large
-2\ln\left( \frac{(1-p)^{n-x}p^x}{(1-\frac{x}{n})^{n-x} (\frac{x}{n} )^x}\right) < c
$$

Thats what we know
$n \in \mathbb{N}, n >250,$
$p \in (0,1)$,
$x \ge 0 , n>x$, $c>0$

Can you solve the equation by x? If not, what other possibilities are there?

Thanks alot

Comment: can you tell us something about the variables?

Comment: Using properties of the logarithm, you get terms like $x\log x$. I suspect there's no analytical solution, and numerical is the only way to go.